# 何故コミュニティwikiの質問が作成できない？

Tags: サポート, コミュニティwiki

回答の場合は自分でコミュニティwikiにできます。なぜ質問はコミュニティwikiに作成できないのでしょうか？(モデレーターによるコミュニティwikiへの変換は別で)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

必要性がないからではないでしょうか。回答をコミュニティWiki にするのは、主にコメントで答えが出てしまって、このままだと未回答だし承認できないんだけど状態を回避したい場合に、自分はこの回答を整理目的で投稿します、といった場合だと理解しています。(なので reputation はつかないし、いらないですよ、と)

このような目的で行われる質問があるケースは、ちょっと想像しづらいです。(逆に、 モデレーターに Community Wiki 化される質問とはどんな質問なのだろう。。？)

Comment: メインサイトでコミュニティWikiにする必要が出ることはまずないでしょうね・・・メタサイトならFAQとかで質問も自由に編集してほしいとかあるでしょうけれど。（メタでは編集提案ができないというのもあります）

Answer (score 3):

かつては「質問」の投稿画面でもコミュニティwikiでの投稿を行うチェックボックスが用意されていたようですが、"間違った使い方" が多いので敢えて無効にした…という経緯があるようです。

- サイトに慣れていない人にとっては「コミュニティwiki」と言われても何を意味するのか分からない
  例: チェックボックスがあるからとりあえずチェックしておこう
- 機能は理解しているけど、本来想定しているものとは違う使い方をしてしまう
  例: マイナス票を受けたくない (信用度を失いたくない) のでコミュニティwikiで投稿

**参考:**

- [Community Wiki checkbox missing in action - MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67581)
- [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67039)